# What is the proper way to make api calls and get the author information of each post by id?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, axios

I'm building a blog app and I want to list all the posts stored in MongoDB. Each post object has an author id, and I want to get the posts and then get the author name of each post and add it as an attribute to the post object.

I defined the methods getUserById and getPosts to make api calls to a Node.js backend, and they both work fine.

Now I'm doing something like this in the useEffect hook of the component, which does not work properly:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const fetchPosts = async () => {
      const res = await getPosts();
      let posts = res.data;
      posts.map(async (post) => {
        const res = await getUserById(post.userId);
        post.username = res.data.username;
      });
      setPosts(posts);
    };
    fetchPosts();
  }, []);
```

I'm wondering what is the proper way to implement something like this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Let add `async` to effects `function` and `await` for `fetchPosts()`:

```
useEffect(async () => {
    const fetchPosts = async () => {
      const res = await getPosts();
      let posts = res.data;
      posts.map(async (post) => {
        const res = await getUserById(post.userId);
        post.username = res.data.username;
      });
      setPosts(posts);
    };
    await fetchPosts();
  }, []);
```